# split a dataframe to multiple tables based on conditional search

Tags: r, split

I have a table like:

```
ID A10 A11 A12 A20 A21 A22 A30 A31 A32
Apple 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
Banana 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
Pear 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
```

My first question is, can I use something like `"*"` to subset multiple column? Like if I want to subset columns containing `A2` (A20, A21, A22), how can I do it quickly?

My second question is how can I split this dataframe to multiple tables? I would like to split this dataframe base on `"A1"` `"A2"` and  `"A3"` (related with my first question), which will be:

```
df1<-
ID A10 A11 A12
Apple 1 1 1
Banana 2 2 2
Pear 3 3 3

df2<-
ID A20 A21 A22
Apple 1 1 1
Banana 2 2 2
Pear 3 3 3

df3<-
ID A30 A31 A32
Apple 1 1 1
Banana 2 2 2
Pear 3 3 3
```

How can I do that?

For another case, I have a dataframe that the character length of the column names are different, like:

```
ID BSS20 BSS40 BSS60 W01 W02 W03 BW20 BW40 BW60 SS20 SS40 SS60
Apple 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
Banana 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
Pear 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
```

How can I split the data into three new dataframes, each one must contain `W0`, like:

```
df1<-
ID BSS20 BSS40 BSS60 W01 W02 W03
Apple 1 1 1 1 1 1
Banana 2 2 2 2 2 2
Pear 3 3 3 3 3 3

df2<-
ID BW20 BW40 BW60 W01 W02 W03
Apple 1 1 1 1 1 1
Banana 2 2 2 2 2 2
Pear 3 3 3 3 3 3

df3<-
ID SS20 SS40 SS60 W01 W02 W03
Apple 1 1 1 1 1 1
Banana 2 2 2 2 2 2
Pear 3 3 3 3 3 3
```

My columns are composed of `*20 *40 *60` and three special characters `W01 W02 W03`, how can I express them well in r?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can split the dataframe to multiple tables using `split.default`. In this case we can extract first two characters from the column names to split them

```
split.default(df[-1], substr(names(df)[-1], 1, 2))

#$A1
#  A10 A11 A12
#1   1   1   1
#2   2   2   2
#3   3   3   3

#$A2
#  A20 A21 A22
#1   1   1   1
#2   2   2   2
#3   3   3   3

#$A3
#  A30 A31 A32
#1   1   1   1
#2   2   2   2
#3   3   3   3
```

If you want to add first column to each of the list you can `cbind` it to every list

```
lapply(split.default(df[-1], substr(names(df)[-1], 1, 2)), cbind, df[1])
```

---

**EDIT**

For the updated data we can create two groups, common columns(`common_cols`) and different columns (`diff_cols`)

```
common_cols <-c("ID", "W01", "W02", "W03")
diff_cols <- setdiff(names(df), common_cols)
```

then do the split only on `diff_cols` and `cbind` the `common_cols` to each list.

```
lapply(split.default(df[diff_cols], substr(names(df[diff_cols]), 1, 2)), 
        cbind, df[common_cols])

#$BS
#  BSS20 BSS40 BSS60     ID W01 W02 W03
#1     1     1     1  Apple   1   1   1
#2     2     2     2 Banana   2   2   2
#3     3     3     3   Pear   3   3   3

#$BW
#  BW20 BW40 BW60     ID W01 W02 W03
#1    1    1    1  Apple   1   1   1
#2    2    2    2 Banana   2   2   2
#3    3    3    3   Pear   3   3   3

#$SS
#  SS20 SS40 SS60     ID W01 W02 W03
#1    1    1    1  Apple   1   1   1
#2    2    2    2 Banana   2   2   2
#3    3    3    3   Pear   3   3   3
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what if the lengths of the characters are different?

Comment: @leeleelee we need to change the answer based on your dataframe. Can you update your questions with your actual data?

Comment: Certainly, I will add below

Comment: I have finished editing my question, thanks again for the help!

Comment: @leeleelee I have updated the answer. See if it helps in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You can split multiple data frame using below code.

```
df <- read.table(text="ID A10 A11 A12 A20 A21 A22 A30 A31 A32
Apple 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
Banana 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
Pear 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3",header = T)


df1<-df[ , grepl( "A1" , names(df) ) ]
df2<-df[ , grepl( "A2" , names(df) ) ]
df3<-df[ , grepl( "A3" , names(df) ) ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What if I want to grepl more than two characters? I tried 'df1<-df[ , grepl( "A1","A2" , names(df) ) ]' but it doesn't work

Comment: you can use or condition in grepl